# Can't get it back to loop. C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to get it back to loop if they enter anything from the choices. everytime I enter 4, it just ends. and if I pick the right one it also ends. Is there anyway I can get it to ask user to input the right one?

```
void towsoncourse ()
{
    cout << "Enter Course: 1 is COSC,2 is ENGL,3 is MATH" << endl;
    int course;
    bool finish;

    bool finishcourse = true;
    cin >> course;

    while (finishcourse != true)
    {
        cout << "Enter correct number for course" << endl;
        if (course == 1 || course == 2 | course == 3)
        {
            finish = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<< "Error: Enter number corresponding to course." << endl;
        }
     }

     switch (course)
     {
        case 1:
            cout << "COSC" << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "ENGL" << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "MATH" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Error: Enter number corresponding to course" << endl;
    }
}

int main ()
{
  towsoncourse ();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo: `if (course == 1 || course == 2 | course == 3)` should probably be `if (course == 1 || course == 2 || course == 3)` or you're up to something real subtle and probably need some brackets.

Comment: So you initialize `finishcourse` to `true`, and immediately afterwards you attempt do something `while` `finishcourse` is not `true`. Does this make sense to you? This is like putting your dinner into the oven, and then planning to do something as long as there's nothing in the oven. Does not compute.

Comment: Note: A decent compiler set to a decent warning level would tell you that `bool finish;` is set but never used. Never ignore compiler warnings. they are there for a reason. Find out what it means and resolve it. You'll almost always have to hunt less bugs.

Comment: @user4581301 agree, my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but rather a guide to point the way.

You want to keep reading an input until it is one of 3 possible values.  So a good place to read and test the input would be inside a loop, exiting only when the test conditions are met.

while loops test continue criteria before each execution.  do loops test continue criteria after each execution. In you case it is necessary to execute at least once.

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues with the code.

1) `while (finishcourse != true)` condition was wrong. It should be `while (finishcourse == true)`.

2) `finish = true;` assignment was wrong. It should have been `finishcourse = false;`

3) `cin >> course;` should be taken inside the loop. Because if you place it outside, it will lead to infinite loop in case of incorrect entry.

So, Just to ensure readability, I have rewritten the code. I have assumed that it gets back to the loop in case of incorrect entry and in case of correct entry, it terminates.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void towsoncourse ()
{
    bool finishcourse = true;

    while (finishcourse == true)
    {
        int course;
        cout << "Enter Course: 1 is COSC,2 is ENGL,3 is MATH" << endl;
        cin >> course;

        switch (course)
         {
            case 1:
                cout << "COSC" << endl;
                finishcourse = false;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "ENGL" << endl;
                finishcourse = false;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "MATH" << endl;
                finishcourse = false;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Error: Enter number corresponding to course." << endl;
        }
     }
}

int main ()
{
  towsoncourse ();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kunal, Its my first year doing coding and needed another pair of eyes of what I was doing wrong. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @KumaHurricane, If you really think that this answered your question, please mark this solution as approved.